# Django database planning - time series data

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, time-series

I would like some advice on how to best organize my django models/database tables to hold the data in my webapp

Im designing a site that will hold a users telemetry data from a racing sim game. So there will be a desktop companion app that will sample the game data every 0.1 seconds for a variety of information (car, track, speed, gas, brake, clutch, rpm, etc). For example, in a 2 minute race, each of those variables will hold 1200 data points (10 samples a second * 120 seconds).

The important thing here is that this list of data can be as many as 20 variables, and could potentially grow in the future. So 1200 * the number of variables you have is the amount of data for an individual race session. If a single user submits 100 sessions, and there are 100 users....the amount of data adds up very quickly.

The app will then ship all this data for a race session off to the database for the website. The data MUST be transferred between game and website via a CSV file. So structurally I am limited to what CSV can do. The website will then allow you to choose a race session/lap and plot this information on separate time series graphs (for each variable), and importantly allow you to plot your session against somebody elses to see where differences lie

My question here is how do you structure such a database to hold this much information?

The simplest structure I have in my mind is to have a separate table for each race track, then each row/entry will be a race session on that track. Fields in this table will be the variables above.

The problem I have is:

1) most of the variables in the list above are time series data and not individual values (e.g. var speed might look like: 70, 72, 74, 77, 72, 71, 65 where the values are samples spaced 0.1 seconds apart over the course of the entire lap). How do you store this type of information in a table/field?

2) The length of each var in the list above will always be the same length for any single race session (if your lap took 1min 35 then you all your vars will only capture data for that length of time), but given that I want to be able to compare different laps with each other, session times will be different for each lap. In other words, however I store the time series data for those variables, it must be variable in size

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: What's your definition of a huge table? How many records? A database like PostgreSQL is made for billions of records per table. Performance comes from smart queries and useful indexes. The size of a table doesn't matter that much, don't worry about it unless you have proof that table size is your problem.

Comment: well I guess size isnt as much of an issue here as the structure of the database for time series data. For example, do I create a separate table for each race session, with each row being a time entry ascending from beginning of the race to the end? This way you would end up with hundreds of thousands of tables (one for each uploaded race).

Comment: Or do you have a finite number of tables (one for each track), each row being a race session on that track. Then the fields are the variables (speed, gas, brake etc) and find some way to store time series data within each of these fields?

Comment: "do I create a separate table for each race session", why? You add new records, you don't create new tables when you need new records. One table can hold billions of records, don't worry about this. We process about two hundred million records per day in a single table, nothing to worry about. Speed comes from smart queries and indexes, not the size of a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that may help you with HUGE tables is partitioning. Judging by the postgresql tag that you set for your question, take a look here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html

But for a start I would go with a one, simple table, supported by a reasonable set of indexes. From what I understand, each data entry in the table will be identified by race session id, player id and time indicator. Those columns should be covered with indexes according to your querying requirements.

As for your two questions:
1) You store those informations as simple integers. Remember to set a proper data types for those columns. For e.g. if you are 100% sure that some values will be very small, you can use `smallint` data type. More on integer data types here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT

2) That won't be a problem if you every var list will be different row in the table. You will be able to insert as many as you'd like.

So, to sum things up. I would start with a VERY simple single table schema. From django perspective this would look something like this:

```
class RaceTelemetryData(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(..., index_db=True)
  race = models.ForeignKey(YourRaceModel, index_db=True)
  time = models.IntegerField()
  gas = models.IntegerField()
  speed = models.SmallIntegerField()
  # and so on...
```

Additionaly, you should create an index (manually) for (user_id, race_id, time) columns, so looking up, data about one race session (and sorting it) would be quick.

In the future, if you'll find the performance of this single table too slow, you'll be able to experiment with additional indexes, or partitioning. PostgreSQL is quite flexible in modifying existing database structures, so you shouldn't have many problems with it.

If you decide to add a new variable to the collection, you will simply need to add a new column to the table.

EDIT:

In the end you end up with one table, that has at least these columns:
user_id - To specify which users data this row is about.
race_id - To specify which race data this row is about.
time - To identify the correct order in which to represent the data.

This way, when you want to get information on Joe's 5th race, you would look up rows that have `user_id = 'Joe_ID' and race_id = 5`, then sort all those rows by the time column.

Comment: so maybe Im not understanding, or I didnt describe the problem properly earlier, but in your django model you have (for example) gas and speed as fields that hold single values. However, in my case, for each race gas and speed each need to be a time series of their own. Because I need to record the players speed every 0.1 seconds for the entire duration of the race - this means the speed field needs to hold 1000+ ordered values (ie representation of the players speed every 0.1 seconds of that race session). How do you fit something like this into an intfield?

Comment: You don't squeeze those 1000+ values into one field. You create 1000+ RaceTelemetryData objects which results in 1000+ rows in the database table. One for every 0.1 second of the race. Then you can iterate over those objects to create an array if you need one, or query the table using an explicit SQL.

Comment: ah I see, do you end up with those 1000+ rows in a table, then the table itself represents 1 race session. This means over the entire site, you end up with hundreds of thousands of tables (one for each race that gets submitted). This is a more preferred method than just fitting an entire time series (probably json string) into a single field and having much fewer tables? I dont have much db experience so this is honestly just all new to me

Comment: I answered by editing. You have just one table, and each row in that table contains data that is needed to identify which users race it is about.

Comment: Imagine that at one point you have millions of race sessions, wouldnt it be a problem at that point to have millions of tables? Is there any db performance issue because of that ?

Comment: When you have millions of tables instead of one huge table you're making it harder for DB engine to optimize queries and to keep any kind of usefull cache. Also some DB engines can compress tables to save on disk space and that would be much less efficient with many tables than with just one big table. And there is the way you construct queries. With 1 table you can use much more versatile WHERE clause to go through data then trying to pick information in the FROM or JOIN sections. And the list of reasons for one big table vs many small tables goes on... You can use partitions if you must.